# Share/Merge Android projects on a Local area Network (Windows)

Tags: android, eclipse, git, tfs, repository

Please suggest any local repository tool that can be used to set up a local server and client machines to share and work on android projects. I do not want to put the projects on online server. I am using eclipse IDE for android and for now using TFS plugin to share project code with my team(But it uses online repository). 
Any tool with Eclipse plugin to commit/merge code will be great.

P.S. My team needs the code access through local area network.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you clone your TFS repository to Git?

You can just clone to a shared location if you already have Git. If you are using TFVC then you can use Git-TF to clone the server repository locally and push to the server when you have a connection.